# Firebase: allow OAuth from a locally run Shiny application

Tags: r, firebase, shiny

I am locally developing a Shiny application that uses Firebase in production. I'd like the Google sign-in button to function within the local deployment of the application. However, I am receiving this error:

```
Firebase: This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console. (auth/unauthorized-domain)
```

`Localhost` is already an authorized domain within my Firebase settings. How can I allow Google sign-in from within the local Shiny application?

Comment: It will be easier if you provide us with the full code of your Shiny app

Comment: I am facing the seme problem.